# How can I automatically make new computings after I have modified some value in a field in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, fields-attributes

I'm a computer programmer and I have no idea about geographic things.
I have got a long algorithm with a lot of computings, computed from a previous computed field. There are 7-8 computed fields and they refer to each other, so it's a bit complex algorithm. There is a chance, that the original values in the beginning of the long algorithms will change (some empty columns will have values and the algorithm needs to compute from them). How can I make this to be as automatic as it can be? I think there is other solution than run the python scripts on the fields again and again.

Comment: If you are working with shapefile, it is worth using the date for table- dBase file. It is changing after every update.

Comment: I have no idea how to do what you said.

Comment: Have you checked this question ? http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/33921/update-a-field-attribute-in-one-column-based-on-a-change-to-another-column-in-on I think that @RyanDalton's answer could help you

Comment: Shapefile consists of few files, one of them is dbf file. Store the date of last modification somewhere (separate text file). At the beginning of your script do something like pytime = time.ctime(os.path.getmtime("D:/scratch/abcd.dbf")). If no changes found, quit script.

Comment: But if a modification happened, how can I call the other scripts from a script? How can I write a script what works on every fields?

Comment: I've done this in an Enterprise sense using triggers from the 'on value change' trigger. I don't think that dBase IV supports triggers but JET (MS Access) does, to an extent, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1105872/access-2007-triggers-and-procedures-equivalents but you may need to convert your function to another form for it to work as intended. Be aware that you shouldn't change OID/Geomertry fields using your trigger/procedure - stay away from the Esri fields and you'll be fine! Create the personal geodatabase first in catalog and then add procedures.

Comment: It's a simple gdb with shape files