# Automatically calculate field with every new entry?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, file-geodatabase, python-parser

I have a point feature class that has a "Direction" field (north, northwest, west, etc; linked to a domain with 16 options). I then have a numeric field "Rotation" that controls the rotation of the feature, based on the string in the "Direction" field.

The value of the numeric field "Rotation" is based on a simple python script of "if" conditions to determine the numeric value of "Rotation" based on the strings from "Direction".

For example, if the point has "Direction" field 'North', the rotation field is 0. If it is 'South', it is 180, and so on.

Is there a way to set up the "Rotation" field to update automatically for every new entry in the attribute table?

Comment: If you digitize new features in ArcMap, you can choose to create multiple feature templates with default values predefined. http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/creating-new-features/creating-new-feature-templates.htm

Comment: This question *may* be similar enough to give you some ideas: https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/33921/43

Comment: @AlexTereshenkov I think it would be worth expanding your comment into an answer

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at Esri's [Attribute Assistant](http://solutions.arcgis.com/shared/help/attribute-assistant/).  This is an add-in for ArcMap that provides a range of different automation options for populating fields in a feature class.

One of the options is the [Field Trigger](http://solutions.arcgis.com/shared/help/attribute-assistant/documentation/methods-attribute-operations/#field-trigger) which

> Updates a field to a specified value when the value of another field is updated.

And another that might be of use to you, depending on your actual requirement, is the [Junction Rotation](http://solutions.arcgis.com/shared/help/attribute-assistant/documentation/methods-all-methods/#junction-rotation) tool, which

> Stores the rotation angle of a junction feature based on connected edge features.

The Attribute Assistant takes a bit of setting up, but I find it works very well, is very configurable, and there are a lot of other options for things you may have never considered.